# Passing a dynamically allocated array of pointers by reference C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
void parseFile(unsigned *line, char **matrix)
{

  FILE *fp;
  char buff[cols];
  char ***ptr;
  ptr = &matrix;

  fp = fopen("cazino_heist_maffs.csv", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    // return 1;
  }

  int i = 0;

  while (fgets(buff, 255, (FILE *)fp) != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d: %s\n", *line, buff);

    for (i = 0; buff[i] != '?'; i++)
    {
      matrix[*line][i] = buff[i];
    }

    (*line)++;
    char **tmp;
    tmp = realloc(matrix, sizeof(matrix) * ((*line) + 1));
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
      printf("fail");
      // return 1;
    }

    matrix = tmp;
    for (int i = *line; i < (*line) + 1; i++)
    {
      matrix[i] = malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
}
```

So I have this method to read from a file and fill a pointer to arrays. The function works inside the method however when I go back to main the matrix isn't filled.

```
  printf("ALL: \n");
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < *line; i++)
  {
    for (unsigned j = 0; matrix[i][j] != '='; j++)
    {
      printf("%c", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
```

If I put this inside the function it works fine but if I put it in the main it doesn't work.

```
   char **matrix;
   matrix = malloc2dArray(rows, cols);

   //
   parseFile(&line, matrix);
```

Also this is how I call the method. I assume I pass my matrix by value instead of reference however I am not sure how to do it with the double pointer. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

To pass an variable to a function "by reference", you pass its address.  You have a `char **`, which means its address has type `char ***`.  So make that the parameter type for the function.

```
void parseFile(unsigned *line, char ***a_matrix)
{
    char **matrix = *a_matrix;
    // do stuff
    *a_matrix = matrix;
}
```

And pass in the address:

```
parseFile(&line, &matrix);
```

Comment: I tried it but its not working.The print statement works inside the method but doesnt work in the main. I get a segmentation error ```      for (unsigned j = 0; matrix[i][j] != '='; j++)``` on this statement. EDIT: Ok my bad I didnt realise I eneded to put my stuff instead of the do stuff comment, why is it like that tho can you explain it to me?.

Comment: Also I did try the triple pointer and just using *matrix in the function which didnt work. Why is that not a valid replacement?

Comment: @chrisbasmaci It is a valid replacement.  The crash means you're doing somethings else wrong.  Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: @chrisbasmaci I suspect `char buff[cols];` should be `char buff[255];`

Comment: your way gives no valgrind errors btw. Is it possible that the "matrix[*line][i]" is not working when I just use *matrix because Im dereferencing it wrong? I would change it with " *matrix[*line][i] "

Comment: @chrisbasmaci It should be `(*matrix)[*line][i]` otherwise you're dereferencing the wrong things.

Comment: Ah ok thanks I suspected that was the case but didnt know how to fix it. Is there a reason why you chose the other way instead of this one? This one seems more straightforward no?